# Prove definite-integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

So...Try it again. 
The last time I did task:

```
Prove equation
```

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$

$a,b$ $are$ $  constants$

Solution:

1. Left part of equation $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = F(b) - F(a)$
2. Right part of equation $\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx = -\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)d(a+b-x)$ then $-(F(a+b-b) - F(a+b-a))$ and result $-(F(a)-F(b)) = F(b)-F(a)$
3. $F(b) - F(a) = F(b) - F(a)$

We see the same asnwer and proved it.

```
Now I have new task. Prove equation:
```

$\int_{0}^{a}x^3f(x^2)dx = \frac12\int_{0}^{a^2}xf(x)dx $

I don't know how to prove it. I hope my question is correct right now.

Comment: I'm no expert but I don't think $d(a+b-x)$ makes sense for notation, and especially since $a$ and $b$ are constant (I assume)?

Comment: @m1cky22 you're right $ a  $ and $b$ are constants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u=a+b-x$. then $dx=-du$ and 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_a^bf(x)\,dx&=\int_{(a+b)-a}^{(a+b)-b}f(a+b-u)(-du)\\&=-\int_b^af(a+b-u)\,du\\&=\int_a^bf(a+b-u)\,du
\end{eqnarray}

Then let $u=x$ and you're done with the first.

For the second, let $u=x^2$. Then $du=2xdx$, so

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^ax^3f(x^2)\,dx&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^ax^2f(x^2)(2xdx)\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{a^2}uf(u)\,du
\end{eqnarray}

Then substitute $x=u$ and you are finished.

Comment: The last expression:
Why $a^2 = a$ ?

Comment: The last integral is in terms of $u$ which equals $x^2$ so $x=a$ becomes $u=a^2$.

Comment: The limits on integrals are actually equations. $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ actually means $\displaystyle\int_{x=a}^{x=b}f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But, can we use newton leibnitz theorem in the last integral?

Comment: Yes, for some function $y=G(x)$ satisfying $\frac{d}{dx}G(x)=xf(x)$ it is true that $\displaystyle\int_0^{a^2}xf(x)\,dx=G(a^2)-G(0)$.

Comment: Okay, I see. But $\int_{0}^{a^2}xf(x)dx $  I think its not simple integral

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $\mathrm{u=x^{2}}$. Also, $\mathrm{d(a+b-x)}$ does make sense as notation, the integrator is a+b-x. $\mathrm{d(a+b-x)=d(a)+d(b)-d(x)=-d(x)}$ as a and b are constants.

Comment: $\mathrm{du=2xdx}$ so $\mathrm{udu=2x^3dx}$

Comment: The limits are $\mathrm{0^2=0}$ and $\mathrm{a^2}$. After the substitution, change the dummy variable of integration back to x to get the result you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Simply use substitution of variables, and find the new limits of integration.

For the first use the substitution:
$$
a+b-x=t
$$
so that:
$$
x=a  \iff  t=b \qquad;\qquad x=b \iff t=a
$$
and 
$$
-dx=dt
$$
so the integral becomes:
$$
\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx=-\int_b^af(t)dt=\int_a^b f(t)dt
$$

for the second integral use the substitution:
$$
x^2=t 
$$
that gives $$
x=0 \iff t=0 \qquad x=a\iff t=a^2
$$
and 
$$
2xdx=dt$$

Can you do from this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that relies on the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) instead of
substitution:

Let $\phi(t) = \int_a^t f(a+t-x) dx -\int_a^t f(x)dx $. Then $\phi(a)=0$,
and $\phi'(t) = f(a) + \int_a^t f'(a+t-x) dx - f(t) = f(a)+f(t)-f(a) -f(t)= 0$,
and so $\phi = 0$.

Let $\eta(t) = \int_{0}^{t}x^3f(x^2)dx - \frac12\int_{0}^{t^2}xf(x)dx$,
we have $\eta(0) = 0$ and
$\eta'(t) = t^3f(t^2)-{1 \over 2} (t^2 f(t^2) 2t) = 0$ and so
$\eta = 0$.

Comment: Well..its correct. But i don't think that it's true way.
But thank you!

Comment: @BorisMolostvov: It is good to have alternative approaches :-)